# JScrollPane Column Header with Frozen, and Scrollable Components

Tags: java, swing, jscrollpane

I have a `JScrollPane` with a column header consisting of multiple components.  One of the components needs to be statically positioned, while the other components need to scroll like normal.

The only thing I could think to do was add a listener to the scrollbar which sets the location of the frozen component like this:

```
frozenHeader.setLocation(scrollViewport.getVisibleRect().getLocation()).
```

However, the location won't actually update until the scrollbar is no long scrolling, so it looks rather unappealing.  And yes, I've tried calling `revalidate()` followed by `repaint()` on both the `frozenHeader`, and its parent.

Here is an example to reproduce what I'm talking about:

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;

/**
 *
 * @author brian
 */
public class TestScroll extends JFrame {
    private JScrollPane scrollPane;
    private JPanel viewport;
    private JPanel colHeader;

    // This should be frozen
    private JPanel frozenHeader;
    // This should scroll
    private JPanel scrollHeader;

    public TestScroll() {
        this.setSize(new Dimension(500, 400));
        this.setResizable(false);
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        // Set up the scroll pane
        scrollPane = new JScrollPane();
        viewport = new JPanel();
        viewport.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(1000, 400));
        scrollPane.setViewportView(viewport);

        // Set up the scroll panes column header
        colHeader = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
        frozenHeader = new JPanel();
        // Width is equal to the frame's width, as it should stay in the same location
        frozenHeader.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(500, 30));
        frozenHeader.setBackground(Color.RED);

        scrollHeader = new JPanel();
        // Width equal to viewportview's as it should scroll
        scrollHeader.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(1000, 30));
        scrollHeader.setBackground(Color.BLUE);
        JLabel label = new JLabel("Text");
        scrollHeader.add(label);

        GridBagConstraints c = new GridBagConstraints();
        c.anchor = GridBagConstraints.WEST;
        c.gridx = 0;
        c.gridy = 0;
        colHeader.add(frozenHeader, c);
        c.gridy = 1;
        colHeader.add(scrollHeader, c);
        scrollPane.setColumnHeaderView(colHeader);

        add(scrollPane);
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new TestScroll().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

I want the `frozenHeader` (Red Panel) to always be centered in the screen instead of scrolling off the screen, and the `scrollHeader` (Blue Panel) to continue to scroll as it does in the example.

To add a little more context, the reason I am not simply putting the `scrollHeader` in the viewport, or moving `frozenHeader` out of the column header and simply placing it above the `JScrollPane` is because the `JScrollPane` in my actual application has an upper left corner panel which is the same height as the column header.  Due to the nature of what the application does, I need to utilize all of the screen space.

Any advice on how this could be accomplished would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Ahh, think I'm going to need to see some example code that replicates what your talking about...

Comment: One way you can do is, put the scrollable components in JScrollPane and add the header on top of JScrollPane. I hope you are referring vertical scrolling.

Comment: Sorry I updated the post, the scrollable and fixed header must remain in the header, because I can't waste screen space.

Comment: `The only thing I could think to do was add a listener to the scrollbar which sets the location of the frozen component` - I don't see this code anywhere? If you post the code maybe we can improve on it.

Answer (score 1):

> "I want the Red Panel to always be centered in the screen, instead of scrolling off the screen."

The problem is that you're setting the `columnHeaderView`. This could easily be accomplished but just setting the add the `colHeader` panel as independent entity, and *not* setting the `columnHeaderView`

```
    colHeader = new JPanel(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.CENTER, 0, 0));
    colHeader.add(frozenHeader);
    JPanel panelForScrollPaneAndScrollHeader = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
    panelForScrollPaneAndScrollHeader.add(scrollHeader, BorderLayout.NORTH);
    panelForScrollPaneAndScrollHeader.add(scrollPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);

    add(colHeader, BorderLayout.NORTH);
    add(panelForScrollPaneAndScrollHeader, BorderLayout.CENTER);
```

Here is the result when doing this

[image]

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;

public class TestScroll1 extends JFrame{
    private JScrollPane scrollPane;
    private JPanel viewport;
    private JPanel colHeader;
    private JPanel frozenHeader;
    private JPanel scrollHeader;

    public TestScroll1() {
        frozenHeader = new JPanel();
        frozenHeader.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(500, 30));
        frozenHeader.setBackground(Color.RED);

        scrollHeader = new JPanel();
        scrollHeader.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(1000, 30));
        scrollHeader.setBackground(Color.BLUE);

        scrollPane = new JScrollPane();
        viewport = new JPanel();
        viewport.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(1000, 400));
        scrollPane.setViewportView(viewport);


        colHeader = new JPanel(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.CENTER, 0, 0));
        colHeader.add(frozenHeader);
        JPanel panelForScrollPaneAndScrollHeader = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
        panelForScrollPaneAndScrollHeader.add(scrollHeader, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        panelForScrollPaneAndScrollHeader.add(scrollPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        add(colHeader, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        add(panelForScrollPaneAndScrollHeader, BorderLayout.CENTER);


        setSize(new Dimension(500, 400));
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);

    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                new TestScroll1().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: In your example the `scrollHeader` doesn't actually scroll, it's just centered.  I wish I could just move `frozenHeader` out of the column header, and place it above like you are doing with both `frozenHeader` and `scrollHeader` in your example, but then I would be significantly decreasing the height of the viewport (because the column header would still be the same height, due to the corner panel as stated in the question + the height of the frozen header I placed above).

Comment: _"I want the Red Panel to always be centered in the screen, instead of scrolling off the screen."_ - I was just going off your exact quote. Now you're saying this is _not_ what you want?

Comment: Sorry, I thought I was clear enough, considering the title, first sentence, and sample code variable names all reference a frozen, and scrollable component being used in the column header.  I have now updated my post and the code a little bit, to hopefully paint a better picture of what I need to accomplish.